# Focus to a specific tab in primefaces tabview

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces tabview .

```
<p:tabView>
<p:tab id="basic" title="Login">
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

On viewing the saved information, suppose I need to edit the data on 'contact' tab only, how can I redirect or focus to that tab directly without going to other tabs.Can I do it with javaScript?

```
My primefaces version is: primefaces-3.0.M3 with JSF and Google Cloud SQL
```

Comment: Is your problem solved? The answer of curious does not seem to solve your problem, but yet you have marked it accepted. If the answer of curious has actually solved it after all, please leave a comment on his answer to provide feedback on it. Or if you actually found a different solution which really solves your problem, then you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @ BalusC: when I editing some information partially,as per curious,the answer is fine. First of all I was trying for that. That's why I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
f:ajax render="myid" 
 on the selection logic and then give id 
"myid" to the 
    p:tabView id="myid"  and then use Rendered attribute on each tab whom you want to display for ex: 
    rendered="#{selectionlogicvariable==tabid}"

Comment: When I use rendered, the tab other than `rendered="true"` will disappears, but I just need to focus on that tab and others should be there!Hope you got that!